# How to use a table in R from an imported file that has blank cells?

Tags: r, import

I'm trying to use a table I have on an external file by importing it and using it to make some graphics, but it was giving me an error message about the blank spaces so I googled it saw some people filling it with -999 so I did the same and also tried with null but none of them seem to be working because it appears it's considering these values... How can I make it so these values are considered non-existing ?

My script:

```
datafilename <- "SGX.txt"
person.data  <- read.table(datafilename,header=TRUE)

panel.cor <- function(x, y, digits=2, prefix="", cex.cor, ...)
{
    usr <- par("usr"); on.exit(par(usr))
    par(usr = c(0, 1, 0, 1))
    r <- abs(cor(x, y))
    txt <- format(c(r, 0.123456789), digits=digits)[1]
    txt <- paste(prefix, txt, sep="")
    if(missing(cex.cor)) cex.cor <- 0.8/strwidth(txt)
    text(0.5, 0.5, txt, cex = cex.cor * r)
}

pairs(~O3_s+NO2_s+CO_s1+CO_s2+T_ref+HR_ref+HA_ref+PP_ref+Rad_ref+VV_ref+DV_ref+P_ref, data=person.data,
      upper.panel=panel.smooth, lower.panel=panel.cor, 
      pch=20, main="SGX Scatterplot Matrix")

summary(person.data)

boxplot(person.data)
```

Answer (score 0):

What you describe is known as missing values and there is a special symbol for those in R (and many other languages): `NA`. Many functions in R also have special ways of dealing with missing values so you should always make sure that you actually use `NA` for missing values.

Try to read your data as follows, where you can specify the blank cells (and NA entries) as missing values:

```
person.data  <- read.table(datafilename, header=TRUE, na.strings = c("NA", " "))
```

Comment: It's my first time handling R but I've done like you said and it's now looking like this:
 person.data  <- read.table(datafilename, header=TRUE, na.strings = c("NA", " "))
but when I do a graph the NA shows up instead of the supposed calculated value considering it as non existing.